# Linked server "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I made a linked server with Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'TEST', 
                                @srvproduct=N'Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver', 
                                @provider=N'MSDASQL', 
                                @datasrc=N'TEST'
```

It worked fine still I used WIndows Authentication Mode, but when I created a login user and switch to SQL AUthentication it did not work.

What changes are needed to work with SQL Authentication?

In providers I have enabled:"Nested queries","Allow inpocess", Level zero only".

The error is:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST" returned message
>   "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string
>   attribute". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST"
>   returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name
>   not found and no default driver specified". Msg 7303, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST".

Answer (score 0):

This error message can occur because of one of these problems.

- One of the initialization parameters specified in `sp_addlinkedserver` (`data_source, location, provider_string, or catalog`) is incorrect for this provider.

  Verify that these parameters defined for the linked server, specified by executing
   `sp_addlinkedserver`, are correct for the given provider.

  Check [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226395%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) also [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- Login and password sent to the provider is invalid.

  Verify that there is a valid login and password configured for the linked server and the current SQL Server login through `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`.

Go through this [Article](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server)

**UPDATE**

During a linked server connection (for example, when it processes a distributed query), the sending server provides a login name and password to connect to the receiving server on its behalf. For this connection to work, you must create a login mapping between the linked servers by using SQL Server system stored procedures. --[HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188477%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You need to create login mapping for linked server [see security for Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537.aspx)

Use [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Creates or updates a mapping between a login on the local instance of SQL Server and a security account on a remote server.

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin [ @rmtsrvname= ] 'rmtsrvname' 
     [ , [ @useself= ] 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' | 'NULL'] 
     [ , [ @locallogin= ] 'locallogin' ] 
     [ , [ @rmtuser= ] 'rmtuser' ] 
     [ , [ @rmtpassword= ] 'rmtpassword' ]
```

Comment: I think is not a provider problem if it works fine when I switch to Windows authentication mode...or I have to change the provider or something in the linked server connection to work fine in SQL SERVER authentication mode?

Comment: @Me5 Please check the updated answer, You need to create login mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection to the linked server works fine using Windows Authentication, but it doesn't using a SQL Server Authentication, I would have a look at the properties of the linked server and make sure, choosing the tab "Security", that both the authentication modes are enabled:

[image]